# Track user actions after opening app from Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I am new to the game of analytics. I recently integrated firebase dynamic links into my ios app. It works smooth with all the redirection.

Mine is a simple Q&A Forum app. It has features like

- View Question
- Reply Question
- Follow Question

When I send a dynamic link to a question page, then I want to track

- Number of people opening the link (`dynamic_link_app_open`)
- Number of people replying (`reply` with question id as custom parameter)
- Number of people following (`follow` with question id as custom parameter)

I have individual events for all the above.

What I am not sure is how do I tie them together?

Comment: Do you want to check how many people replied/followed/opened (splited by these categories) the app with your dynamic links? And by individual events I guess you mean Firebase Analytics events, right?

Comment: I have all the individual events on Firebase. But what I want to do is measure how many people who opened app from link, replied/followed the question.